# Secure file only for specific user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was able to protect and serve static files only for authenticated users.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/files/images/**").addResourceLocations(rootPath);
```

However I want only the User who owns that file can access it. Should I create some controller or create Filter to implement that feature? Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: yes this will need a custom filter to check if file owner is accessing the file.

Comment: Maybe use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128806/spring-security-how-to-restrict-user-access-certain-resources-based-on-dynamic)?

Comment: @muasif80 thanks, I think I will go with filters

Comment: @Lino I think I defined the question not so good, I was mentioning not Rest-ish resource just a some files that User uploaded